# Where is the Ubuntu `*.deb` repository for `qtfm`?

Tags: deb, filemanager, qt5

I would like to try the `qtfm` file browser but [https://www.qftm.org] has vanished.

Does anybody know of a `.deb` repository from which to install `qtfm`? Can it be installed from source code:

```
$ ./configure
$ ./make
$ ./make install
```

Comment: Download qtfm-master.zip from [GitHub - rodie/qtfm: Qt File Manager](https://github.com/rodlie/qtfm) To install its dependencies in 18.04 run `sudo apt install libqt5widgets5 libqt5gui5 libqt5concurrent5 libqt5dbus5 libqt5corea ffmpeg imagemagick udisks hicolor-icon-theme adwaita-icon-theme libavdevice57 libswscale4 libavformat57 libavcodec57 libavutil55 libmagickwand-dev libmagickcore-dev libmagick++-dev`

Comment: What repository are these in? When I try apt-get tells me package could not be found. I have enabled all the standard repositories, e.g. Universe, Multicast, etc.

Comment: Do I then follow the standard procedure:   ... $ cd ./qtfm-master  $ ./configure --help  $ ./configure <options>   $ make  $ sudo make install.  I only ask because too many of my attempts at installing from source code fail.

Comment: Your suspicions about following the standard procedure for installing qtfm are correct. [GitHub - rodie/qtfm: Qt File Manager](https://github.com/rodlie/qtfm) provides its own installation instructions. Under these circumstances providing a .deb file would be ideal, but sadly I did not find one. The sad truth is that Qt File Manager does not provide good support. It's a fact that many people don't know that the default nautilus file manager in Ubuntu is highly configurable.

Comment: Nautilus is unusable for the simple reason that basic functionality like a file tree browser gets removed (not just hidden--removed) for touch screen compatibility.